# google now web api

Tags: google-api

Подскажите, можно ли работать с google now через WEB API, то есть отправляя запросы на URL получить подсказки например в JSON или в XML формате.
Как мы их получаем в google поиске на Android (Например "Напомни мне принять лекарство завтра в 6 утра", поставит напоминание), так же чтобы он не выполнял действие, а отправлял ответ что нужно сделать, то есть на ту же команду он должен вернуть ответ что мы должны поставить напоминание на завтра в 6 утра.

Если это не возможно, можно хотя бы определения слов получить, по типу вот этого, только через API:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно на виртуальной машине запускать браузер, делать скриншот экрана, считывать данные и отправлять пользователю :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вовремя спросили. Google Knowledge Graph Search API выпустили на этой неделе(!). Даже результаты англоязычного поиска в самом гугле по этому запросу ещё не успели обновиться.
https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/
http://geektimes.ru/post/268382/

Comment: Вроде работает, но у меня получается находить только фильмы, знаменитости и т.д. Но определения слов, он почти не знает (выводит только название фильмов, за исключением нескольких слов), так и должно быть? Я так понял что это база данных вообще определений, а не только фильмов и т.д.

Comment: На официальной странице API перечислены поддерживаемые сущности. Абстрактных определений я среди них не увидел. Но в поиске они обычно берутся из Википедии, у которой тоже есть API. Пожалуйста, в дальнейшем оформляйте дополнительные вопросы именно как вопросы, а не комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, насколько мне известно компания не предоставляет api для Google Now. И нужные для вас по функционалу сервисы мне не встречались. Не исключено что их просто нет. Если вы обладаете знаниями программирования среднего уровня, для вас не составит труда самостоятельно написать такой сервис.

Comment: а что на счёт вот таких подсказок, которые показываются даже в браузере?  http://joxi.ru/0KAgzdMH6gGY2l.jpg

Comment: Эти подсказки являются частью "Google Поиска". "Google Now" доступен только для мобильных устройств. Можно убедится на этой странице:
https://www.google.com/landing/now/

Comment: Даже получить определение этого слова не получится?